# Minted text changes _ to \_ in the final PDF

Tags: lyx, minted

I'm writing a report and I found something wrong after compiling it. The PDF file showed things like `\_` instead of `_` and `\textquotedbl{}` instead of quotation marks. It's pretty important for me to fix this since the report has a lot of code in it, and you can imagine how many underscores and quotation marks there are.

[image: What I see]

If it helps, I'm using LyX and compiling with pdflatex.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\setminted{frame=lines,framerule=2pt}
\mdfsetup{topline=false, bottomline=false,leftline=false, rightline=false}
\surroundwithmdframed{minted}

\newgeometry{left=3cm}
\linespread{0.5}
\begin{minted}{fortran}

 !------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 file_dimension = "dimensiones_prueba.dat" 
 file_magnitud = "orden_magnitud_prueba.dat"

/

\end{minted}
\linespread{1.0}
\restoregeometry
```

Edit: I put the text inside an ERT box and it fixed the formatting issue, even though it changed the font and spacing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post a minimal example .lyx file (it is just text so you can copy/paste). For more information, see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see it in my test.

Comment: @Au101 Thank you very much, I'm not used to this kind of Q&A model ^^.

Comment: @egreg What I see is this: http://anony.ws/image/J4kl (I hope I'm allowed to post these kind of links)

Comment: @Romanchio You can add the image to your question using the button above the editing window; if the system says you can't because of low reputation, just remove the `!` in front of the produced text and a user with enough reputation will reinsert it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, hope somebody reinserts it ^^

Comment: @Romanchio Not that link, which is to a site which this one can't display images from. Click edit, then hit Control-G and the system will ask you for a picture from your machine.

Comment: @Romanchio Did you read the link I mentioned? It would be nice if you could post a complete minimal example .lyx file. I suggest you post both the .lyx and the exported .tex files. By the way, welcome to TeX SE!

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks. Sorry to ask, but how can I post that without hosting it on an external site? I guess there's a way to do it just like with pictures.

Comment: @Romanchio open the .lyx file in a text editor, copy everything, and paste it in a "code" block just like the current code block that you have. On Ubuntu, you can just right-click, open with Gedit, ctrl+a to select all, copy, etc.